# How to hide label in edge in visjs graph?

Tags: javascript, canvas, vis.js

I would like to display label only when edge is selected, is there a library method to do this?

Eventually I thought about having a store for edge properties including label, is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method.

What you can do is listen to the `selectEdge` events, and when an edge is selected, remove it's label. When the edge is deselected, add it's label again.

Comment: How about this: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/tests/hidden_edge_test.html

Answer (score 2):

I've found this workaround to be easiest way to achieve it:

```
var options = {
    edges: {
        font: {
            size: 0
        },
        chosen: {
            label: function (values, id, selected, hovering) {
                values.size = 14;
            }
        }
    }
}

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

**Explanation:**

The font size of all edges is set to 0. 
The font size of selected edge is set to desired value.

**Side note:**

For some reason this approach doesn't work.

See:
https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/4112

Comment: Works fine. Also add after network is instatiated: var showEdgeLabel = function (e) {
    this.body.data.edges.update({
      id: e.edge,
      font: {
        size: 14
      }
    });
  };

  var hideEdgeLabel = function (e) {
    this.body.data.edges.update({
      id: e.edge,
      font: {
        size: 0
      }
    });
  };

  network.on('hoverEdge', showEdgeLabel);
  network.on('blurEdge', hideEdgeLabel);

Answer (score 0):

If the edge's `label` field is set then the label is shown. There is no way to configure that to behave differently. To hide the label, simply move the value to a hidden field such as `_label` or `label_hidden`. Then when you are ready to show the label do `edge.label = edge._label`.

One heads up: if you `delete edge.label` and update it via `DataSet.update` then it will not be deleted. You have to set it to `""` or `null`.